# Съезд последнего контейнера на строку ниже

Tags: css, вёрстка, html, frontend

```css
.features {
  width: 695px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2px;
}

.f2 {}

.f3 {
  /**float:right;**/
}

.features>*:first-child p {
  color: #22795b;
}

.features>*:nth-child(2) p {
  color: #b27cf5;
}

.features>*:last-child p {
  color: #d0974e;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">

  <div class="f1">
    <center>
      <img src="img/1.png" alt="Фиксированные цены">
      <p>Фиксированные цены</p>
    </center>
  </div>

  <center>
    <div class="f2">
      <center>
        <img src="img/2.png" alt="Определенные сроки">
        <p>определенные сроки</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>

  <center>
    <div class="f3">
      <center>
        <img src="img/3.png" alt="Гарантированная сатисфакция">
        <p>гарантированная сатисфакция</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>

</div>
```

Пробовал применять display:inline-block; ко всем тегам "center" и "div" внутри "div class="features"", к сожалению не помогло, за ранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stack overflow! На какую строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, правильно ли я поняла, но есть такой вариант:

```
.features {
  width: 695px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2px;  
  text-align: center;
}

.f1, .f2, .f3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

//дальше все как было

https://jsfiddle.net/yacfLyh6/